# View TraceWriter.Info() logs in Azure Function without Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

My Azure Function app uses the TraceWriter.Info() method to write logs. Very simple to use and it used to be very simply to view:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 22 * * *", RunOnStartup = false)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info("My log!");
}
```

However, now when I go to the portal and click the "Monitor" tab, which used to show the output in a console-like window, it demands that I setup Application Insights whilst giving me an error:

[image]

I cannot click the "Configure" button to set it up. As far as I know my app specifies nothing about Application Insights, yet the error seems to suggest that it does.

My questions:

- Is it possible to get the old console window back?
- Failing that, why can I not configure app insights?

Comment: can you check if this key `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` is present in the app settings blade of the function app ? if so, you need to remove it.

Comment: Yes, have responded to answer from @Joey Cai with more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the old console window back?

As Thomas said, I add the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in Application settings of function and could reproduce your problem. So, after deleting the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`, you will get the old console window back.
[image]

> Failing that, why can I not configure app insights?

After deleting that attribute you will  configure app insight successfully. And it will generate a specific app insight for your function app.

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for the response. I actually figured it out as there was an APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY entry in the Application Settings section; I'm still getting used to controlling settings in the portal rather than config files. I didn't know deleting it would bring the console back, but I've actually created a new AppInsights instance and added the key to my function and it's working. My function only runs periodically so it hasn't triggered yet; does this setup still let me see the TraceWriter.Info() log output?

Comment: @MSOACC, if you have an App Insights instance wired up to your function application, you should definitely be able to find your TraceWriter logs, as well as other information that wasn't available in our old monitor view. Here is some more information about what app insights gives you: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights